# issue with proxy when using conda update and only when putting the loging and pwd in the command line

Tags: python-2.7, proxy, anaconda

I am new with anaconda. I got Anaconda install on a Windows 7 machine:

```
H:\>conda info
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Current conda install:

             platform : win-64
        conda version : 4.0.7
  conda-build version : 1.20.3
       python version : 2.7.11.final.0
     requests version : 2.10.0
     root environment : C:\Program Files\Anaconda2  (writable)
  default environment : C:\Program Files\Anaconda2
     envs directories : C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\envs
        package cache : C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\pkgs
         channel URLs : repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
                        repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
                        repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
                        repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
          config file : C:\Users\xxxx\.condarc
    is foreign system : False
```

I started to update and install python packages with the following command:
conda update python
conda update –all
everything was working fine. I had to enter my login and password and everything was working well.

and then I started to have issue with the proxy. See the details below :
-   It asked me my username and I put my MY_LOGIN
-   Then it asked me my password and the issue start. If I try to put my password, I see the all the character I am entering which is not correct. When I tape enter I am asked again to put my password and then the system is frozen and I need to close the application !
-   I am using the following .condarc file :

```
  proxy_servers:
    http: xxx-vip1.ch.doleni.net:8080
    https: xxx-vip1.ch.doleni.net:8080
```

below the output of the previous commands

```
H:\>conda update python
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata:
https proxy username: MY_LOGIN
https proxy username: Password: MY_PWD

https proxy username: Password:
```

I find a way to have it working but I don’t understand why. See the details below :
-   If I put my login and my password in the .condarc file everything work well again:

```
proxy_servers:
  http: xxx-vip1.ch.doleni.net:8080
  https: https://MY_LOGIN:MY_PWD@xxx-vip1.ch.doleni.net:8080
```

- Everything is working well as illustrated below

below the output of the previous commands

```
H:\>conda update python
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: .........
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\Program Files\Anaconda2:
#
python                    2.7.11                        4
```

Any idea why putting my login and pwd in command line doesn’t work anymore while putting it in the .condarc works ?
I got the impression that after the update of the python packages the issue started (At some point I got some messages asking if I wanted to install software from untrusted source).
Could it be some issue with the cyber security of my company ? I would like to have a clear understanding of the reason before contacting the IT of my company.

Maybe the IT security team should  add the list of web URLs (which conda contacts to for downloading the package) in the exception list.

> repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/
>   repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/ 
>   repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64/
>   repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/

but when I had the issue it was working well for a friend and he started to have the same issue one day later.

Thanks a lot
Cheers
Fabien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to conclude this thread, that the only way to not have this issue was to remove the package **futures**. The authors of this package claims this is an issue on conda side. 

More details here: [link to Github of this package](https://github.com/agronholm/pythonfutures/issues/56) . Since then I didn't have any issue.